# Rails 4 How do I set custom set of parameters to a user without update function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a system to count calories and macro intake. Each user has a "calorie_goal" as well as "carb/protein/fat_goal". It gets set depending on his or her parameters(like height, weight, etc.) and gets updated every time user edits his profile. Now I want to let user set his macro goals alone that would not depend on his weight/height/etc. I created a form for it:

```
<% @user = current_user %>

<%= form_for(@user, :url => :update_macros) do |f| %>

  <table>

    <tr>
      <div class="field">
        <td><%= f.label :calorie_goal, "Calories" %></td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :calorie_goal %></td>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="field">
        <td><%= f.label :carb_goal, "Carbs" %></td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :carb_goal %></td>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="field">
        <td><%= f.label :protein_goal, "Protein" %></td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :protein_goal %></td>
      </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="field">
        <td><%= f.label :fat_goal, "Fat" %></td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :fat_goal%> </td>
      </div>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <div class="button-set">
      <%= f.submit "Update", :class => "button-green update-button" %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", user_url(current_user),   :class => "button-green cancel-button" %>
    </div>

  </div>



<% end %>
```

Which goes to user#updt_macros

```
    def updt_macros
    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|

      if @user.validate_macros(user_params)

        @user.manual_macros(user_params)

        @user.save

        format.html { redirect_to @user}
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path, notice: 'Update unsuccessful' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

User.rb for validate_macros and manual_macros

```
def manual_macros(params)

    self.calorie_goal = params[:calorie_goal]
    self.carb_goal = params[:carb_goal]
    self.protein_goal = params[:protein_goal]
    self.fat_goal = params[:fat_goal]
    self.fiber_goal = self.calorie_goal / 100
    self.sugar_goal = self.calorie_goal / 30


  end

  def validate_macros(params)

    validates :carb_goal, presence: true
    validates :protein_goal, presence: true
    validates :fat_goal, presence: true

    validates_numericality_of :carb_goal, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
    validates_numericality_of :protein_goal, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
    validates_numericality_of :fat_goal, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0

  end
```

which gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `validates' for #<User:0x007fd62ada2660>
```

How do I validate for specific attributes of user? And am I doing manual_macros method right? Is it going to work?

Comment: validates is a class method provided by ActiveRecord and not an instance method of a User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually validates the attributes by `validate_macros`, All you have to do is set the attributes first and then call `save` , If some of the attributes are missing/invalid then the record wont be saved automatically. You can set the automatic values by callbacks i-e `before_save` . It will also make sure that if some one changes any of the dependent attributes some where in application or in console then the updated values will be stored.

Updated `manual_macros` : I remove automatic values from this method

```
def manual_macros(params)
    self.calorie_goal = params[:calorie_goal]
    self.carb_goal = params[:carb_goal]
    self.protein_goal = params[:protein_goal]
    self.fat_goal = params[:fat_goal] 
  end
```

**User.rb**

```
before_save :set_atuomatic_values

private

def set_atuomatic_values
 self.fiber_goal = self.calorie_goal / 100
 self.sugar_goal = self.calorie_goal / 30
end
```

Now in  **user#updt_macros**

```
def updt_macros
    @user = current_user
    @user.manual_macros(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|

      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user}
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path, notice: 'Update unsuccessful' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is a [Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to ActiveRecord Callbacks.

**SECOND METHOD**

Secondly if you don't want to do it in callbacks then you can call `valid?` method of `user` after setting `manual_macros` and then set automatic attributes after words.

```
 user#updt_macros

def updt_macros
    @user = current_user
    @user.manual_macros(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|

      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user}
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path, notice: 'Update unsuccessful' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**User.rb**

```
   def manual_macros
        self.calorie_goal = params[:calorie_goal]
        self.carb_goal = params[:carb_goal]
        self.protein_goal = params[:protein_goal]
        self.fat_goal = params[:fat_goal]
        return unless self.valid?
        self.fiber_goal = self.calorie_goal / 100
        self.sugar_goal = self.calorie_goal / 30
    end
```